# Error with domain propagation on AWS Route 53 after domain transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, windows-server-2012, amazon-route53

So, I transferred several domains from a separate AWS account to my current one via Route 53, and none of the transferred domains are propagating or pointing at my new account's instance properly.

It has been 48 hours and nothing has changed. Inside of this time period I have purchased new domains and set up their DNS settings, creating new, working websites, so I doubt it's just a matter of "waiting out" the transferred domains to make sure they propagate.

As an example, *casasites.io* started on my original account, and was transferred. It is currently not working and I am unable to ping it.

Here's a screencap of the settings.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjMDJ.png

You can see the A record is pointing to my instance's elastic IP, and it has been assigned proper Amazon DNS servers. However, I can't even ping this domain name. It returns nothing... the MX record still works for my email, don't ask me how.

---

Here's a screenshot of a domain I bought and set up in the last 24 hours on my current AWS account. The settings that matter are the same. I can ping this domain and get a response from my EC2 instance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe3CA.png

For reference here's what I see when I ping one, then the other.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqCiE.png

**TL;DR - Domains I transferred from one AWS account to another won't work, can't even ping them. Domains I set up on my own do work. Can't tell why.**

I am obviously not an expert in regards to DNS stuff, so any light shed on the situation would be very helpful and appreciated.

## EDIT - Resolved

AWS assigns the nameservers when you create a hosted zone for the registered domain. Typically this is done when you buy it and the user doesn't have to manually assign anything.

Since they were instead transferred, I got two different sets of nameservers and Route53 didn't alert me to this. Still a simple error on my part. Thanks all.

Comment: That casasites.io route53 screenshot, is that from 'old' or from current AWS account?

Comment: casasites.io is an "old" domain and those are its current settings on my current account. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: When (from your current account) go to 'Route53','Registered Domains', click on 'casasites.io', please look at (or give us screenshot) of Name Servers part (in upper right)

Comment: @dusan.bajic here you go. http://i.imgur.com/63k4DIS.png Edit: I think I just made a big stupid mistake...

Comment: @dusan.bajic you were on the right track. AWS assigns the nameservers when you create a hosted zone for the registered domain. Typically this is done when you buy it. Since they were instead transferred, I got two different sets of nameservers and Route53 didn't alert me to this. Still a simple error on my part. If you want to post a full answer I'll give you credit for it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for providing real domain names, that made troubleshooting pretty straightforward (people are sometimes paranoid and and hide real data which make DNS debugging almost impossible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transferring a Domain to a Different AWS Account will not automagically change any associated data (although in your case it probably could do so), which is reasonable since it is possible that someone needs domain registration associated with one account and the corresponding hosted zone associated with another account.

So, to quote [AWS docs:](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-between-aws-accounts.html)

> **Important:** 
>   If you want to transfer the hosted zone to another account,
>   you must manually create the new hosted zone, create resource record
>   sets in the new hosted zone, and **update your domain with the name
>   servers for the new hosted zone**.